# Selenium Webdriver no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, firepath

I am new python selenium webdriver Student.

I want to click() next button but it's not working.

I am stuck here few days.

Thanks you any help.

**Message Error**:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='next_button']"}
```

**This is my code**:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='next_button']").click()
```

**this is webpage source**:

```
<div id=“banner" class="shell" style="width: 786px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">
<input id=“json" value=“x" type="hidden">
    <div class="shell">
        <div class="border">
            <div id="header" style="height: 135px;">
            <div id="navigation">
            <div id="main" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                <div id="content" class="left" style="padding: 30px 0px 20px; left: 250px;">
                    <style>
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="inPn" style="width: 100%;background: #ffffff">
                            <div class="detail">
                                <h3>Example Event</h3>
                                <table class="fit">
                                    <colgroup>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr valign="middle">
                                            <td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
                                                    <img id=“back_button" src="https://www.site/back.png" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                    <img id=“next_button" src="https://www.site/next.png" style="cursor: pointer;margin-top: 10px;"
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't inside an IFRAME and it's visible? BTW, don't use XPath for something like this ... use `.find_element_by_id("next_button")`. XPath is slower, more brittle, and has inconsistent support between browsers. Prefer id then CSS Selectors... then if you need to get an element by the text it contains use XPath.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest waiting for the page to load using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='next_button']")))
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='next_button']").click()    
except TimeoutException:
    print 'Timeout - No tag found'
    continue
```

or use:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//img[@id='next_button']"))
```

Comment: error is **Timeout - No tag found**
but im sure xpath is right , becoz i use firepath,

Comment: Which webdriver are you using?

Comment: i use chromedriver on mac python2.7

Comment: ok, then that should not be the issue. As a last possibility I would try  the following: element = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='next_button']")))

Comment: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='next_button']").click()

Answer (score 0):

As your element requires to get image from `src`, you might need to wait some time until target element appears on page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

button = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@id='next_button']")))
button.click()
```

Comment: i do your suggest, it's not work, this error **'WebDriver' object is not callable**